# Stack level too deep when trying to destroy a child record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, destroy

I'm trying to destroy a record that belongs to a parent record. However Rails won't let me do it because of a `stack level too deep` error.

My classes (simplified) are built like this:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: lambda { |p| p[:image].blank? }

  ...
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album

  mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
end
```

When I try the following, I get the exception:

```
Photo.destroy(12) # where 12 is the ID of the photo I want to destroy
# note that Photo.delete(12) works fine, but doesn't remove the image from the file system
```

I don't understand why destroying the photo would trigger this error. Maybe it's `carrierwave` with its `mount_uploader`?

**EDIT 1:** This has definitely something to do with `carrierwave`. In my uploader I have the following code which gets called many many times (until the stack is too deep):

```
def unprocessed_image_filename
  match_data = /^original_(.+)_\d{14}\.\D{3,4}$/.match(File.basename(model.image.to_s))

  match_data ? match_data[1] : "photo"
end
```

This is used to determine the name of the various versions.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my `unprocessed_image_filename` to use: `model.read_attribute(:image)` instead of `model.image.to_s` appears to have done the trick.

Now I've got different issues, but at least I can destroy photos as I wish.